# SQL create new column based on a less than operand of another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to create a new column based on the amount of an existing column. I am getting an error with my code below and I understand it is because <=, >= type operands can only return one record. I believe I should be using an IN or ANY, ALL possibly operand but cannot seem to implement it properly.

```
ALTER TABLE SALES_TOTAL ADD REFUNDS INTEGER(20);

UPDATE SALES_TOTAL SET REFUND = SELECT [SALE_TOTAL] from [SALES_TOTAL] WHERE[SALES_TOTAL] < 10
```

Could anyone provide an example of how to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error? "Single-row subquery returns more than one row" ?

Comment: Yes indeed -     "subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
"

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov has answered your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what you probably want:

```sql
alter table SALES_TOTAL add REFUNDS int unsigned not null default 0;
update SALES_TOTAL set REFUNDS = SALE_TOTAL where SALE_TOTAL < 10;
```

Comment: Suppose there are fifteen rows whose sale_total is less than 10. Which value would be picked?

Comment: @I_am_Batman, sql is smart enough to pick corresponding row. Just test it. https://gist.github.com/809cc8e6c2dffa9378d9566661facdf1